# Update query is modifying all the records

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have an update query which will compare fields in two tables and if the field's are different move over the new field (table2) into table 1. Then update the 'New', 'Changed', 'Preexisting' fields in table 2 to true. But what happens is it's marking all the changed, and preexisting fields to true. It does copy the changed data into table 1, but for some reason it's marking all records imported to true.

SQL

```
UPDATE [NAVAIR Deficiencies] INNER JOIN NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp 
ON [NAVAIR Deficiencies].[Unique Deficiency Code] = NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp.[Unique Deficiency Code] 
SET [NAVAIR Deficiencies].[Hull Q] = [NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp]![Hull Q],
    NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp.Changed = True, 
    NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp.Preexisting = True
WHERE ((([NAVAIR Deficiencies]![Hull Q])<>[NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp]![Hull Q])) 
   OR (((Nz([NAVAIR Deficiencies]![Hull Q]))<>[NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp]![Hull Q]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the query is performing as expected. You have an INNER JOIN with a WHERE statement following, which means that any records which do not meet the ON condition as well as the condition(s) of the WHERE statement will not be part of the result set. You have then specified that `[NAVAIR Deficiencies].[Hull Q] = [NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp]![Hull Q]`, `NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp.Changed = True`, and `NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp.Preexisting = True` for that result set, meaning that your output will have the Hull Q values from the temp table, True for Changed, and True for Preexisting across all records where Hull Q has a different value in the temp table than it has in the base table.

Comment: But it's changing the Changed and Preexisting to true for every record from the temp table. Even when I know there were no changes between the two. How would I get it to update just the changed field values?